# "Order on behalf of"

Tags: vocabulary

If I were to place *"orders on behalf of"* Jack, then what is the word I would use to refer Jack?

I could not figure out what I would call Jack in one word, if I were to inform that in an email or in correspondence to someone else.

I need the answer on the likes of assignee-assigner. Can someone help?

Thanks

-Sid

Comment: You could try 'client'. You would then be Jack's 'agent'.

Comment: I thought of that initially, but it would not look good on an email. Any other word? Thanks

Comment: OK, so this isn't a generic question - you need to elaborate on the relationship (beyond ordering stuff for him) that you have (or want to portray that you have) with Jack...

Comment: Here it goes. Kim is a nurse in the hospital, and she is supposed to place "orders on behalf of" Jack, who is a provider/doctor. I am supposed to describe this in an email to my client. What is the word I can use to refer Jack.

Comment: In industry, Kim would simply be referred to as a "Buyer" or "Purchaser" - they are real job titles! Not sure about health-care. Perhaps "procurer", though that has other connotations!

Comment: @Sid In that situation, Jack would simply be the "doctor" or "provider".  Kim, on the other hand, may be a "proxy" or "agent" or simply "nurse".  This type of relationship tends to use professional titles rather than descriptive ones.

Comment: @Richard, That makes sense. I did the same and refered them in actual context that is as provider and nurse. Can you make that as an answer, and I'll accept it. thanks for your time.

Comment: Sure!  At the time, it didn't seem like an answer, but now, reading over it again, it does.  Posted.

Answer (score 2):

You are describing a *principal-agent* relationship. A *[principal](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/principal)* is

> A person for whom another acts as an agent or representative:
>   *stockbrokers in Tokyo act as agents rather than as principals*

An *[agent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/agent)* is

> A person who acts on behalf of another.

[*Oxford Dictionaries Online*]

In connection with the orders, Jack is your *principal*.

These terms are used more in business and law than in casual conversation.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal to in this case that we would refer to Jack by our relationship to him.

If this is someone that we work with with then we can say:

> I am ordering on behalf of my *colleague*.

This can  be used when your colleague isn't just the person at the next but practically anyone in the same organisation. They could be your boss but the person you're talking to doesn't need to know that and probably doesn't care.

Obviously we can put a variety of things in there as appropriate: friend, mother, family member, client, gardener, neighbour, someone I met recently who just needed some help etc.

Answer (score 0):

In that situation, Jack would simply be the "doctor" or "provider". Kim, on the other hand, may be a "proxy" or "agent" or simply "nurse". This type of relationship tends to use professional titles rather than descriptive ones